# how to get listview data from parseJson

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, listview

hi please answer my question 
i have this code in eclipse for Android Developing.
i am using mysql and php for database and get data with JSON . But i dont know how can i use JSONparse data in listview . please edit my codes.

```
public class ViewAllPersons extends Activity {

String url = "http://192.168.1.206/androhp/view_all_persons.php";
ArrayList<String> result;
ListView list;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_all_person);
    result = new ArrayList<String>();
    LoadAllPersons lap = new LoadAllPersons();
    lap.execute(url);
}

class LoadAllPersons extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        InputStream jsonStream = getStreamFromURL(args[0], "GET");
        String jsonString = streamToString(jsonStream);
        parseJSON(jsonString);
        return null;
    }

    void parseJSON(String JSONString) {
        try {

            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(JSONString);

            JSONArray allpersons = jo.getJSONArray("allpersons");
            for (int i = 0; i < allpersons.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = allpersons.getJSONObject(i);
                String objString = "";
                objString = object.getString("name") + " , "
                        + object.getString("name2") + " : "
                        + object.getInt("iconlink");
                result.add(objString);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {

        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) { 

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list); 
           String[] web = {
                    "Google Plus",
                        "Twitter",
                        "Windows"
                } ;

                String[] imageUrl = {
                        "http://www.varzesh3.com/football3_Images/varzesh3-logo.png",
                        "http://www.varzesh3.com/football3_Images/varzesh3-logo.png",
                        "http://www.varzesh3.com/football3_Images/varzesh3-logo.png"

                };
        CustomList adapter = new
               CustomList(ViewAllPersons.this, web, imageUrl);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

**How can I use parseJSON data instead of web listview :**

```
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list); 
           String[] web = {
                    "Google Plus",
                        "Twitter",
                        "Windows"
                } ;

                String[] imageUrl = {
                        "http://www.varzesh3.com/football3_Images/varzesh3-logo.png",
                        "http://www.varzesh3.com/football3_Images/varzesh3-logo.png",
                        "http://www.varzesh3.com/football3_Images/varzesh3-logo.png"

                };
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in the custom adapter you have created? If yes please add the that CustomList code?

Comment: No, i dont have any error in custam adapter, just i dont know how can i use parseJSON data instead of web listview .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You have got both data as well as list, now you need to combine them.
first you have to convert your json result into list, where values are your json values.
    final ArrayList<String> listdata = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
      listdata .add(values[i]);
    }

then you have to assign adapter to your list. You can use following code. 
  final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
        android.R.layout.yourlistlayout, listdata );
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

More details 
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html